# In Pig Game (dice) what number is the best to roll for? and why?

Tags: probability, dice

You are given two dice and roll to get points ranging from 2-12 that stack every turn but if you ever roll 7 you lose all your points. I know the probablity of hitting a 7 is 1/6 but what score should I aim for before I hit 7?

Answer (score 3):

On each roll, you have:

- A 5/6 probability of gaining points.  If so, the expected number of points gained is 7.
- A 1/6 probability of losing everything.

Suppose that you already have $x$ points.  Then if you roll the dice one more time, your expected number of points gained is $\frac{5}{6}(7) - \frac{1}{6}x = \frac{35-x}{6}$.  In order for rolling again to be worthwhile, this value must be nonnegative.  So, **roll until you get 35 points, then quit.**